# Is there a term for the trope where a character says something they should not know?

Tags: terminology, trope

Is there a name for the trope where a character betrays himself/herself when they say or do something they shouldn't know? For example, somewhere in the series *Homeland*, Carrie offers Nicholas some tea from his favorite tea brand. This gives away to Nicholas that she has been spying on him.

Some interesting options are given in the comments; however, none of them exactly cover it. The desired term would cover the example I gave and the terms "I never told you my name" and "I never said it was poison," as well as other similar terms/examples.

The terms "saying too much" and "loose lips" are too broad because they do not necessarily entail giving yourself away involuntarily with a detail you shouldn't not know. A drunk babbling away would also be covered by these terms.

Comment: "Saying Too Much" seems an obvious catch-all. Some variation on the " I Never Told You My Name" subset of the "Saying Too Much" trope? Or are you looking for a more spy-specific trope?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Movie & TV Stack Exchange! Your Question could use some clarification. I'm not sure what you mean when you say, ..."offers Nicholas some tea while excusing while she doesn't have his favorite brand." Do you mean to say that she did have his favorite tea brand, which is what gave her away? If you could edit to clarify it could help from keeping your Q closed.

Comment: @DarthLocke, the fact that Carrie knows what Nicholas favorite brand of tea is gives away that she spied on him.

Comment: I'm sure there is a TV tRope were a perpetrator gives themselves away by nknownng details of a crime whichhte police hav eno tmade public, or otherwise knowing too much about what happened. "Inever said that the knife that killed him was a steak knife."  But I can't remember how to look it up.

Comment: @thieupepijn Ok, but that is not how it read...so I'm going to edit to simpify/better clarify.

Comment: @M.A.Golding That would be "[I Never Said It Was Poison](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/INeverSaidItWasPoison)".

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a character unintentionally revealing *that a target is under surveillance* ? Because plain 'unintentional revealing' is simply [Loose Lips](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LooseLips), I would have thought

Comment: I've voted to close this. You've been offered several seemingly good alternatives in comments but are refusing to consider them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say the correct answer to this - which is amongst the examples in the comments (and in the updated question itself!), is [**I Never Said It Was Poison**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/INeverSaidItWasPoison).

From what the OP is asking, it is that the character accidentally gives away an attempt at deception by revealing information that they wouldn't know had they been honest. (in this case, Brody's favourite brand of tea, which Carrie couldn't know unless she was spying on him)

[I Never Told You My Name](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/INeverToldYouMyName) is a bit different (though they may overlap) as it appears to cover any instance of characters unexpectedly knowing other characters' names - even if it's (for example) to assert dominance ("Yes, we know *all* about you!"), rather than simply accidentally revealing they know the person's name when they shouldn't.

Comment: The "I Never Said It Was Poison" page even includes [the exact Homeland scene from the question as an example](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/INeverSaidItWasPoison/LiveActionTV): *"In Homeland, when Carrie and Brody are having a romantic getaway at her family's cabin, she tells him that unfortunately she doesn't have any of his favorite tea, Yorkshire Gold. Unfortunately for Carrie, that is, seeing as Brody never told her what his favorite tea was, and he realizes instantly that she must have been spying on him."*